# Can this captcha be broken using OCR?

Tags: captcha

Can the captchas produced by captchas.net be defeated using OCR software that is currently available?

Example:
[image]

If it can, how easily is such OCR software available and at what cost approximately?

I run a website that gets a lot of abuse and abusers do tend to spend a considerable amount of time in trying to defeat my protections. I wanted to know how easily this captcha can be defeated before implementing it.

I am aware that there are captcha solving services with humans and it is quite impossible to protect against them. I am mainly concerned about these captchas being solved using software at near zero cost.

Comment: Why? What do you care how the CAPTCHA is being bypassed, whether it is via software or humans? Or more generally: why do you care how your site is being abused, whether it is via software or humans - what is important is that it IS being abused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried pytesseract which is a port of tesseract for python and was unable to get the string inside the captcha, however this doesn't mean it can't be broken, there is tons of other library for OCR, and you can even "train" the OCR to get better results.

```
try:
    import Image
except ImportError:
    from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = ''#Insert tesseract exe path

captcha = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(''))#Insert your captcha path

print captcha
```

Here is the link to download pytesseract: [pytesseract](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytesseract)